# Private Variable

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private

Question1:   If I declare a private variable and put in personal information (if I did not create a getter function), does anyone have a way to see this information?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since all the info in the blockchain is public, anybody (who knows enough about how data is stored internally) can read the value in the variable.